# Checking if a Swift class conforms to a protocol and implements an optional function?

Tags: swift

I'm writing a helper function in Swift for use in SpriteKit games that will check if the collision detention has been set up correctly.

I want to check that my GameScene implements the protocol `SKPhysicsContactDeletegate` and also contains the `didBeginContact` function.

I have the following code, written with the help of Xcode's auto-complete:

```
    if GameScene(conformsToProtocol(SKPhysicsContactDelegate)) {
        if GameScene(respondsToSelector(didBeginContact(SKPhysicsContact))) {
            print("Self implements SKPhysicsContactDelegate and didBeginContact appears to be present")
        }
    }
```

Xcode then complains about my `conformsToProtocol`, complaining that

> 'Argument labels '(_:)' do not match any available overloads'

with no suggestion how to fix. It also objects to `respondsToSelector`, stating that

> 'Cannot convert value of type '(SKPhysicsContact).Type' (aka
>   'SKPhysicsContact.Type') to expected argument type 'SKPhysicsContact'

How can I check if my GameScene conforms to this protocol and also implements this function?

Edit: Here's my code based upon the answers:

```
if GameScene.self is SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    print("Yes it's a delegate")
}
```

Output: `Yes it's a delegate`

```
let yy = (GameScene.self as? SKPhysicsContactDelegate)?.didBeginContact
print("yy is \(yy)")
```

Output: `yy is nil`

```
if (GameScene.self as? SKPhysicsContactDelegate)?.didBeginContact != nil {
    print("Yes it's a delegate and the function is there")
}
```

No output.

Comment: Try replacing `GameScene.self` with the actual variable.

Comment: @redent84 - that did the trick - thanks. Just need to check that physicsWorld.contactDelegate is set to 'self' now.

Comment: I've extended my answer to explain the `GameScene.self` scenario

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You are still thinking in Objective-C, embrace Swift!

Assuming that your protocol looks like this:

```
@objc protocol SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    optional func didBeginContact()
}
```

Try this:

```
if let delegate = gameScene as? SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    delegate.didBeginContact?()
}
```

Or a one liner:

```
(gameScene as? SKPhysicsContactDelegate)?.didBeginContact?()
```

Notice the `?` after the method name in the call? It's because that method is optional and it won't get called if the object doesn't implement that method. And the `if let` branch won't get executed if the object doesn't conforms to `SKPhysicsContactDeletegate` protocol.

---

#### Check method existence without call

To check the existence of the method itself before calling, just omit the method call to get a reference to that methodand check it like any other variable:

```
if let method = (gameScene as? SKPhysicsContactDelegate)?.didBeginContact {
    print("gameScene conforms to SKPhysicsContactDelegate and implements didBeginContact")
    // Call it later whenever you want
    method()
}
```

If you don't need to call it later, just check for `nil`:

```
if (gameScene as? SKPhysicsContactDelegate)?.didBeginContact != nil {
    print("gameScene conforms to SKPhysicsContactDelegate and implements didBeginContact")
}
```

---

#### Check for static methods

Checking for `optional static` methods uses the same approach, but requires the class object instead of an instance of the class:

```
if (GameScene.self as? OptionalProtocol.Type)?.staticMethod != nil {
    print("gameScene conforms to OptionalProtocol and implements staticMethod")
}
```

Notice `GameScene.self` for obtaining the object type and `<protocol>.Type` to cast to the protocol class instead of a protocol instance.

---

#### Full sample

Attached full sample for Playgrounds, [Swift script](http://krakendev.io/blog/scripting-in-swift) or any [online Swift compiler](http://www.runswiftlang.com):

```
import Foundation

@objc protocol OptionalProtocol {
    optional func instanceMethod()
    optional static func staticMethod()
}

class Nothing {}
class Something: OptionalProtocol {}
class Bar: NSObject, OptionalProtocol {
    func instanceMethod() {
        print("Instance method")
    }
}
class Foo: NSObject, OptionalProtocol {
    static func staticMethod() {
        print("Static method")
    }
}

// Cast instances to 'Any' and classes to 'AnyClass'
let nothing: Any = Nothing()
let nothingClass: AnyClass = Nothing.self
let something: Any = Something()
let somethingClass: AnyClass = Something.self
let bar: Any = Bar()
let barClass: AnyClass = Bar.self
let foo: Any = Foo()
let fooClass: AnyClass = Foo.self

nothing is OptionalProtocol // false
(nothing as? OptionalProtocol)?.instanceMethod != nil // false
(nothing as? OptionalProtocol)?.instanceMethod?() // Does nothing
(nothingClass as? OptionalProtocol.Type)?.staticMethod != nil // false
(nothingClass as? OptionalProtocol.Type)?.staticMethod?() != nil // Does nothing

something is OptionalProtocol // true
(something as? OptionalProtocol)?.instanceMethod != nil // false
(something as? OptionalProtocol)?.instanceMethod?() // Does nothing
(somethingClass as? OptionalProtocol.Type)?.staticMethod != nil // false
(somethingClass as? OptionalProtocol.Type)?.staticMethod?() != nil // Does nothing

bar is OptionalProtocol // true
(bar as? OptionalProtocol)?.instanceMethod != nil // true
(bar as? OptionalProtocol)?.instanceMethod?() // Prints 'Instance method'
(barClass as? OptionalProtocol.Type)?.staticMethod != nil // false
(barClass as? OptionalProtocol.Type)?.staticMethod?() != nil // Does nothing

foo is OptionalProtocol // true
(foo as? OptionalProtocol)?.instanceMethod != nil // false
(foo as? OptionalProtocol)?.instanceMethod?() // Does nothing
(fooClass as? OptionalProtocol.Type)?.staticMethod != nil // true
(fooClass as? OptionalProtocol.Type)?.staticMethod?() != nil // Prints 'Static method'
```

Comment: This makes me wonder how to check if an object implements a method _without trying to call it_ ? E.g. an optional method takes an argument that's expensive to create, so you'd want to check whether the method is implemented or not before preparing the argument and making the call.

Comment: But I don't want to call the function, only check if it exists... (i,.e. what he said.) you don;t call didBeginContact directly; it is called as part of the SpriteKit game loop.

Comment: @redent84 - so what's happening in your last edit? I can see that you check if GameScene implements the protocol, but won't .didBegincontact actually call the function if it exists or is there something going on that is just checking that the function is there or not?

Comment: `didBeginContact` will get the reference to that method. You can then check if the reference is not `nil` to check if it exists. The method is not being called.

Comment: OK - just verified this by trying it on a func test() and got "SKPhysicsContactDelegate does not contain test" (or words to that effect). However, this isn;t firing as is still returns nil.

Comment: @SteveIves What isn't firing? Could you post your updated code?

Comment: If you use `GameScene.self` you are checking for class methods, but your protocol only contains instance methods. Try replacing the class reference `GameScene.self` with an instance of it.

Answer (score 4):

respondsToSelector fails, because it expects an instance of SKPhysicsContact and not SKPhysicsContact.type.

To check if an object implements an interface, you can use **is**.
So for example:

```
protocol Test {
    func foo();
}

class TestImpl : Test {
    func foo() {
        print("bar")
    }
}

let a = TestImpl()
let b = String()
print(a is Test) // true
print(b is Test) // false
```

Comment: This works for: if GameScene.self is SKPhysicsContactDelegate {