# respondsToSelector on optional delegate methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, respond-to, swift2

I'm converting [this](https://github.com/Boris-Em/BEMAnalogClock) Objective-C open source project to Swift. It has a bunch of optional delegates.

```
@protocol BEMAnalogClockDelegate <NSObject>

@optional

- (void)currentTimeOnClock:(BEMAnalogClockView *)clock Hours:(NSString *)hours Minutes:(NSString *)minutes Seconds:(NSString *)seconds;
- (NSString *)dateFormatterForClock:(BEMAnalogClockView *)clock;
- (NSString *)timeForClock:(BEMAnalogClockView *)clock;
- (UIColor *)analogClock:(BEMAnalogClockView *)clock graduationColorForIndex:(NSInteger)index;
- (CGFloat)analogClock:(BEMAnalogClockView *)clock graduationAlphaForIndex:(NSInteger)index;
- (CGFloat)analogClock:(BEMAnalogClockView *)clock graduationWidthForIndex:(NSInteger)index;
- (CGFloat)analogClock:(BEMAnalogClockView *)clock graduationLengthForIndex:(NSInteger)index;
- (CGFloat)analogClock:(BEMAnalogClockView *)clock graduationOffsetForIndex:(NSInteger)index;
```

I converted them to Swift like so.

```
@objc protocol BEMAnalogClockDelegate {
    optional func currentTimeOnClock(clock: BEMAnalogClockView, hours: String, minutes: String, seconds: String)
    optional func dateFormatterForClock(clock: BEMAnalogClockView) -> String
    optional func timeForClock(clock: BEMAnalogClockView) -> String
    optional func analogClock(clock: BEMAnalogClockView, graduationColorForIndex index: Int) -> UIColor
    optional func analogClock(clock: BEMAnalogClockView, graduationAlphaForIndex index: Int) -> CGFloat
    optional func analogClock(clock: BEMAnalogClockView, graduationWidthForIndex index: Int) -> CGFloat
    optional func analogClock(clock: BEMAnalogClockView, graduationLengthForIndex index: Int) -> CGFloat
    optional func analogClock(clock: BEMAnalogClockView, graduationOffsetForIndex index: Int) -> CGFloat
    optional func clockDidBeginLoading(clock: BEMAnalogClockView)
    optional func clockDidFinishLoading(clock: BEMAnalogClockView)
}
```

In the Objective-C project, before calling these optional methods, it checks its availability using `respondsToSelector` like this.

```
if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(analogClock:graduationColorForIndex:)]) {
    self.graduationColor = [self.delegate analogClock:self graduationColorForIndex:i];
} else self.graduationColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(analogClock:graduationAlphaForIndex:)]) {
    self.graduationAlpha = [self.delegate analogClock:self graduationAlphaForIndex:i];
} else self.graduationAlpha = 1.0;
```

I directly converted this to Swift by making the `BEMAnalogClockDelegate` conform to `NSObjectProtocol` and calling them like so.

```
if delegate.respondsToSelector(#selector(BEMAnalogClockDelegate.analogClock(_:graduationColorForIndex:))) {
    graduationColor = delegate.analogClock!(self, graduationColorForIndex: i)
} else {
    graduationColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
}

if delegate.respondsToSelector(#selector(BEMAnalogClockDelegate.analogClock(_:graduationAlphaForIndex:))) {
    graduationAlpha = delegate.analogClock!(self, graduationAlphaForIndex: i)
} else {
    graduationAlpha = 1
}
```

But this causes a EXC_BREAKPOINT crash when the project is run.

I googled for a solution and came across [this](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/swift-optional-protocol-methods/) article which recommends using `guard let` for this.

However my problem is how do I specify the logic that goes in the `else` part? For example in the first `if else` block above, it checks the method in the `if` block and if it fails, it sets the value for `graduationColor` to `UIColor.whiteColor()` in the `else` block.

How do I do that if I use the `guard let` approach? Or is there a better way to do this overall?

Comment: This answer might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36475215/2976878

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift supports optionals for methods as well.

You can do this instead:

`graduationColor = delegate.analogClock?(self, graduationColorForIndex: i) ?? UIColor.whiteColor()`

Or the long way:

```
if let graduationColor = delegate.analogClock?(self, graduationColorForIndex: i) {
   self.graduationColor = graduationColor
} else  {
   self.graduationColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
}
```